# Mod Rewrite doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I have some problem with a rule in the .htccess file
I need a rewrite rule to change my web address
For example I have this address: 
    www.demo.com/page.php?id=1
And I need to have 
    www.demo.com/1

I tried to use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule argomento.php?id=4 /nomeazienda
```

but it doesn't work.
The server is a linux server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ argomento.php?id=$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ argomento.php?id=$1
```

..incase you don't want to match all characters...